# ¿Como hacer una conexion de sql-server 2008 en php cuando ya esta en un host web?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Ya e echo una conexion a sql server desde xammp y funciona perfecto, la duda es como debo cambiar los parametros de conexion para acceder desde un host web en internet? que puertos debo abrir o que ip debo poner?
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: la ip que tu proveedor de hosting te otorgue además del nombre del usuarios y contraseña que al momento de darte de alta te sean asignados

Comment: esa ip debo ponerla en el puerto que debo abrir?

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, disculpa que responda aquí y no en el comentario que tienes puesto, no tengo reputación suficiente. En el puerto, que yo recuerde, siempre lo he dejado vacío ya que normalmente se rellena automáticamente, la IP que te da el Host para la base de datos va en Host, database o en IP, no sé que nombre tendrá en tu archivo.

Un saludo.